# How to know when Express-Handlebars variables have been replaced in HTML?

Tags: javascript, express, express-handlebars

As far as I know `Express-Handlebars` replaces variables client side which is weird.

I have something like this...

```
<script type="application/json" id="init-props">
  {{{user}}}
</script>
```

and the `user` is being set by Express..

And some javascript waiting to get it from the DOM like so...

`user = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('init-props').innerText);`

But when Javascript tried to read it, it is not there. Because... `Express-Handlebars` even though powered by `Node` replaces `{{{user}}}` on the client side. Why? I have no idea...

Are there any events I can listen to? Any way to force `Express-Handlebars` to render it on the server?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If your client-side JavaScript can't find it because it has been replaced … what makes you think it is being replaced on the *client* and not before it reaches the client?

Comment: What doesn't make sense? If it were server side rendered, it would be written in the HTML itself, and JS would have access to it. But it appears that `Express-Handlebars` is NOT replacing it server-side. It's doing it client-side. Therefore, JS can't find it. Side note, don't down vote my question because you fail to understand it..

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve]. It lacks a *clear problem statement*. You have not shown how you use Express-Handlebars to try to do this replacement. You have shown a Handlebars template. You have not shown how you are passing it through Express-Handlebars. You have not shown the results of passing it through Express-Handlebars. (View > Source in your browser will help with that). Express-Handlebars is a module designed to interact with Express. Getting it to run on the client would require some major hacking, so it is highly unlikely that your assertion that it running on the client is correct